# how change Action Bar title from fragment to fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to change the Action Bar title from fragment to fragment..

example loginfragment to registerfragment..

i have button at loginfragment that will redirect to register fragment..

```
case R.id.textSignup:
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, RegisterFragment.newInstance())
                        .commit();
                break;
```

and i add this code in my registerfragment

```
public static RegisterFragment newInstance() {
        RegisterFragment fragment = new RegisterFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public RegisterFragment () {
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(3);
    }
```

then here is the MainActivity

```
 public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_home);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_login);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_register);
                break;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }
```

the problem is the register title is not displaying even i add onSectionAttached(3) in the registerfragment..

here is the MainActivity Code

```
package com.example.administrator.mosbeau;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    Boolean InternetAvailable = false;
    Seocnd detectconnection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        detectconnection = new Seocnd(this);
        InternetAvailable = detectconnection.InternetConnecting();
        if (InternetAvailable) {
        } else {
            NointernetFragment fragment = new NointernetFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        // NEW STUFF
        if(position == 0){
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, HomeFragment.newInstance())
                    .commit();
        } else if (position == 1){
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, LoginFragment.newInstance())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_home);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_login);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_register);
                break;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }

    }

}
```

thanks

joe

Comment: put break point and debug your code.

Comment: When do you call restoreActionBar method?

Comment: You can use toolbar instead of actionbar

Comment: You already asked this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603010/how-to-change-the-actionbar-title-from-the-fragment-class-in-android-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i.e bcoz you not calling `restoreActionBar()` function anywhere in your code.

you can change actionbar Title as you navigate from fragment to fragment by like this aswell in `onCreateView()`of each Fragment.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Your title");
```

Comment: It's being called in `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: `onCreateOptionsMenu` will be called only once when activity is created. if you want to refresh `onCreateOptionsMenu` then youl have to call `getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();` from fragment

Comment: This isn't the correct place to ask for code to just be given to you. I recently setup a new Android project using the Nav drawer template, which looks similar to yours, and auto-updates the title. Have you tried creating a new blank project, and seeing what's different?

Comment: @joehamirbalabadan.com after `((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))` is been called. refresh `onCreateOptionsMenu` by calling `getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();` since you call your `restoreActionBar()` in it

Comment: getActicity().getActionBar() returns null from onCreateView() inside the fragment at my project...

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to call
getActivity().setTitle(your_title)
in the onCreate() method in all of your fragments